# Change body background of page interval

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var imageID=0;
function changeimage(every_seconds){
//change the image
if(!imageID){
    document.getByTagName("body").src="icwXI.jpg";
    imageID++;
}
else{if(imageID==1){
    document.getByTagName"body").src="JvuP9.jpg";
    imageID++;
//call same function again for x of seconds
setTimeout("changeimage("+every_seconds+")",((every_seconds)*20)); 
</script>
</head>
<body style='background: url(icwXI.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;' onload='changeimage(1)'>
```

The aim is to have the body background image load icwXI.jpg initially and then change to JvuP9.jpg 20 seconds later, then cycle back to icwXI.jpg another 2 seconds later.

However it does not seem to be working, my skills with JavaScript is pretty limited.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you should be using setInterval interval instead of setTimeout.

Answer (score 3):

Create an array of background images - below I have done this with some placekitten images. Secondly, create a function that changes the background out with the next in the array. For tracking our location, we'll use a variable (we could use the `.indexOf` on arrays in newer browsers, though support is weak in some areas).

Lastly, we'll create an interval that runs every 23 seconds. When it runs it calls our swapBG function, and then immediately creates a timeout that will call our swapBG function again after 2 seconds.

```
// backImg for tracking which image we're showing
// dbStyle is a quick reference to the style list on the body
// backgnd is an array of potential background images
var backImg = -1,
    dbStyle = document.body.style,
    backgnd = [
        'url(http://placekitten.com/350/350)',
        'url(http://placekitten.com/349/349)'
    ]; 

// Steps forward through background images, then back to start
// when it reaches the end of the list
function swapBG() {
    dbStyle.backgroundImage = backgnd[ backImg++ ]
        ? backgnd[ backImg ]
        : backgnd[ backImg = 0 ];
}

// Call swapBG() immediately
swapBG();

// Create an interval that runs every 23 seconds
setInterval(function(){
   swapBG();
   // Create a timeout to run after 2 seconds
   setTimeout(function(){ 
       swapBG()
   }, 2000 );
}, 23000);​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XsAWB/2/

Comment: Hi, I decided to go with Mootools as it has the fade effect I am after. After some research I came up with this script but it is not changing the images, any reason why? http://jsfiddle.net/Mykdd/1/

Comment: @Dean You're completely changing the substance of your question.

Comment: How so, I just want the body background image to change and fade in.

Comment: You've gone from asking a JavaScript question, to asking a specifically MooTools question. The JavaScript solution I provided above answers your original question.

Comment: Is MooTools not JS? I was under the impression that it was. I thank you for your effort with the JS one, but it is way too subtle for the design side of things, so I've decided to change and go with MooTools.

Comment: @Dean MooTools is a library of proprietary JavaScript effects and add-ons that you don't get from a vanilla browser. Your code, title, and tags all suggest you want a JavaScript solution. Unless you specifically request frameworks, plugins, or libraries, we don't assume you want them (they aren't always necessary). What is too subtle about the solution above?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12050/discussion-between-dean-and-jonathan-sampson)

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you have a few syntax errors you need to fix. The first two I see are not finishing two beginning `{` brackets, and missing a parenthesis on the second `document.getByTagName`.
2. Your function doesn't "sleep/timeout" for the first time it is called, immediately changing the background image when the function is called.
3. Also note that when you `setTimeout()` the function to repeat it, the second parameter is actually *milliseconds*, not seconds like you seem to intend.
4. Your function will only modify `<body>` twice, since `imageID` keeps increasing, and there are only cases for not-set (which should really be checking for `imageID==0`) and 1. You need to change it, so there are cases for each background you want to rotate through.
5. `document.getTagByName("body").src` is not the correct way to change the background image. `document.body.style.backgroundImage` is.