# Periodical change of background in Webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I am designing a web application.To make it more attractive i thought of having beautiful background in my webpage that changes periodically.I know this came be done in JavaScript. But how to synchronize,so that the DOM changes background at specific time.Suggest me some a function for this..

Comment: changing bk at time intervel surely eats clint's Bandwidth...

Comment: @7-isnotbad will consider my cons of my design and take necessary steps....but tell me method to sync...

Comment: have a look at [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OLuyUWeR/4/edit)**

```
var images = [
  "car.jpg",
  "cow.jpg",
  "pig.jpg"
],
c = 0,
intv;

for(var i =0; i< images.length; i++){
   var img = new Image().src = images[i]; // Preload all images
}

intv = setInterval(function(){
   document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url("+ images[++c%images.length] +")";
}, 2500);
```

Than if you want to stop rolling your interval you can do like:

```
clearInterval( intv );
```

Answer (score 0):

Best Soln  using JQ ,

[jQuery fade to different background images for body set by interval set by a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821273/jquery-fade-to-different-background-images-for-body-set-by-interval-set-by-a-spe)

Try

1)[html5 change background image interval time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495186/html5-change-background-image-interval-time)

2)[Change body background of page interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859384/change-body-background-of-page-interval)